# Adding custom package in Centos 6 DVD/CD

Tags: centos, kickstart, disk-image, installation

I am trying to include my custom build package in the CentOS installer DVD/CD. I am able to respine the DVD with my Kickstart file.

The automated kickstart installation works fine, however, when I try to include my package in the Package dir and update the comp.xml file, it does not work.

I am doing following steps.

Adding my RPM to iso/Packages/ dir. [mypackage.rpm]
Recreating the repo db files by

```
cd /path/to/iso/dir
discinfo=`head -1 .discinfo`
compdata=`find repodata -name *comps*xml`

createrepo -u "media://$discinfo" -g $compdata .
```

Then creating the ISO iamge

```
ISOFILE=$PWD.iso
PACKAGER="Your Name"
ISONAME="RHEL 6.3 x86_64 KVM Respin"
ISODATE="201/06/28"


mkisofs -r -R -J -T -v -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 4 \
    -boot-info-table \
    -V "$ISONAME" \
    -p "$PACKAGER" \
    -A "$ISONAME - $ISODATE" \
    -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
    -c isolinux/boot.cat \
    -x "lost+found" \
    --joliet-long \
    -o $ISOFILE .
```

Now when I use my package name in kickstart

```
%packages --no-base
@core
mypackage
```

During the installation phase I get Ananconda error saysing "mypackage" was not found in the repo.

I tried manually editing the comp.xml file too, but didn't help.

Appreciate if I get any help in getting mypackage.rpm to be able to installed by %package directive or other way.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the '-T' flag.

The replacement TRANS.TBL will often not overwrite an existing one and, thus, your new RPM packages may not be visible in the filesystem.  The -J with -joliet-long options should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I figure this out.

```
ISOFILE=$PWD.iso
PACKAGER="Chandan"
ISONAME="CentOS 6.5"
ISODATE="`date -I`"

sudo mkisofs -r -R -J -T -v -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 4 \
    -boot-info-table \
    -V "$ISONAME" \
    -p "$PACKAGER" \
    -A "$ISONAME - $ISODATE" \
    -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
    -c isolinux/boot.cat \
    -x "lost+found" \
    --joliet-long \
    -o $ISOFILE .
```